# QR/Barcode scanner for browser

Tags: barcode, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am creating a webapp. I need to have in my app a functionality where user can scan in a QR/barcode from the local machine with some device, the image or number series is inserted to our web page fields in the browser.

Is this doable somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do the same thing.  The only solution I found was to use a scanner with a "keyboard wedge", which is a device that places the scanned characters in the keyboard buffer as an item is scanned.  Then user (or your code) has to make sure the cursor is in the correct text box but then the characters just appear as if the user entered them manually.

Comment: It comes with the scanner.  Most scanners will either be a direct connect (USB, etc) or use a keyboard wedge